# c++ - deque::push_front not working

Tags: c++, deque

I have a `std::deque<std::deque<Room*>> rooms` which i'm iterating over with:

```
for(auto row : rooms) {
    row.push_front(new Room());
}
```

but for some reason it just overwrites the first object with a `new Room` instead of inserting the `new Room` before it. If I log the size of the `row` before and after the `push_front` call, it reads out, for example, 1 then 2 (as if it were behaving as expected), but then if i log the size out after the loop, the `row` is back to only having a size of 1.

There isn't much else going on, and I can provide more code if necessary.

Is there something going on in the for loop that i'm not aware of? I'm never seeing the first room destroyed or anything.

Answer (score 3):

Use `auto& row` rather than `auto row` - at the moment you're making a temporary copy of each row rather than modifying the original.